# Cost of calling parent overridden function

Tags: c++, optimization, inheritance, overriding

In the following code:

```
class Base
{
   void funcA();
   void funcB();
   .
   .
};

class Derv : public Base
{
   int m_state;
   void funcA(){ m_state = 1; Base::funcA(); }
   void funcB(){ m_state = 4; Base::funcB(); }
   .
   .
};

Derv a;
a.funcA();
```

Will `Base::funcA()` be a separate function call(`Derv::FuncA() -> Base:FuncA()`), or the code will be inlined?
if it is compiler dependent, does the compilers (e.x GCC) is smart enough to inline it?

Comment: Trying it with such a simple example (compiler optimize everything out) will no be the same as in a complex code. and I got lost in the complex code assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on implementation of `Base::funcA()` and `Base::funcB()`.
If the compiler can then the compiler will inline it.
Most of the Modern day compilers(including gcc) are smart enough to do that.

The C++ standard allows a compiler to perform any optimization As long as the resulting executable exhibits the same observable behaviour **as if** all the requirements of the standard have been fulfilled.

This is known as the **As-If Rule**.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on the compiler. Nothing is guaranteed to be inlined, even using the `inline` directive. Best way to find out would be to look directly in the generated code.

Also, you might find the optimizer to be more than smart. For example:

```
class Base
{
   void funcA() {};
   void funcB() {}; 
   .
   .
};

class Derv : public Base
{
   int m_state;
   void funcA(){ m_state = 1; Base::funcA(); }
   void funcB(){ m_state = 4; Base::funcB(); }
   .
   .
};

int main()
{
   Derv a;
   a.funcA();
   return 0;
}
```

will skip the code completely and just return 0.